# first occurrence of a variable has a value?

Tags: php

I downloaded some files from github (from [this page](https://github.com/daveismynamecom/loginregister), if matters ).

This is for php login stuff, and everything works, but I cannot understand how it is possible.

Here is the typical top part of my pages

```
require('inc/config.php'); // db credentials and connect
require('inc/password.php'); // class password, hashing etc
require('inc/user.php'); // class user
```

one of the first function in `user.php` is the following:

```
...
private function get_user_hash($username){  

    $_SESSION["uname"] = $username; // echo of this variable works
...
```

So, the question is - where the value of `$username` is coming from?

Because there is no such a variable in the preceding files (`config.php` and `password.php`).

This is its first occurrence in entire script workflow and how it is possible that it has some value?

Comment: Thanks a lot. All answers helped me. Solved (I hope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find from where get_user_hash() is called and their will be some argument in it. It is not necessary that it should be named $username.
for ex-

```
  $user="some user name";
  get_user_hash($user);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$username` is an argument of the `get_user_hash` function, which isn't executed until some code elsewhere in your script. Although it appears first, it isn't run first, and the code that calls this function will pass it a value for `$username`.